# Is there an Objective-C (NSString) Equivalent of Java's replaceAll("\\p{Cntrl}", "")?

Tags: java, objective-c, nsstring, replaceall, control-characters

Pretty straightforward question:

Is there an Objective-C equivalent that iOS developers can use with NSString objects to do the same thing as Java's replaceAll("\p{Cntrl}", "") call on a String?

We already have this in Java:

```
String noControlCharsString = maybeHasControlCharsString.replaceAll("\\p{Cntrl}", "");
```

I want something like this in Objective-C too:

```
NSString *noControlCharsString = [maybeHasControlCharsString stringByReplacingControlCharsWithString:@""];
```

Thanks in advance.

AG3

Answer (score 2):

Try to use this one..
This is used to replace character.

```
  NSString *str = @"\\p{Cntrl}AB/bar:baz\\p{Cntrl}foo";
    NSCharacterSet *doNotWant = [NSCharacterSet characterSetWithCharactersInString:@"\\p{Cntrl}"];
    str = [[str componentsSeparatedByCharactersInSet: doNotWant] componentsJoinedByString: @""];
    NSLog(@"%@", str);
```

Other wise 
This is used to replace whole string.

```
   NSString *str = @"\\p{Cntrl} This is a string \\p{Cntrl}";

    str = [str stringByReplacingOccurrencesOfString:@"\\p{Cntrl}"
                                             withString:@""];

        NSLog(@"%@", str);
```

Comment: Thanks but the "\\p{Cntrl}" used in Java is a regex that actually specially matches all control characters that may appear in the string -- not just the actual textual letters making up that special sequence.  I'm looking for a solution that rips out _all_ those control characters.

Comment: What you wanna replace either one by one character or entire string?.

Answer (score 2):

The `stringByReplacingOccurrencesOfString` method of `NSString` has a 
`NSRegularExpressionSearch` option that accepts the same pattern *\p{Cntrl}* as your 
Java method:

```
NSString *maybeHasControlCharsString = @"\nabc\r\ndef\r";
NSString *noControlCharsString =
    [maybeHasControlCharsString stringByReplacingOccurrencesOfString:@"\\p{Cntrl}"
                                       withString:@""
                                          options:NSRegularExpressionSearch
                                            range:NSMakeRange(0, [maybeHasControlCharsString length])];
NSLog(@"%@", noControlCharsString);
// Output: abcdef
```

Answer (score 0):

Try:

```
NSString *noControlCharsString = [maybeHasControlCharsString stringByTrimmingCharactersInSet:controlCharacterSet];
```

EDIT
As Martin R rightly says the above only removes any leading or trailing matches.

Here's a category method which strips all matches from the string:

```
- (NSString *)stringByStrippingCharactersInSet:(NSCharacterSet *)set {
    NSString *r = [self stringByTrimmingCharactersInSet:set];
    NSArray *components = [r componentsSeparatedByCharactersInSet:set];
    components = [components filteredArrayUsingPredicate:[NSPredicate predicateWithFormat:@"self <> ''"]];
    return [components componentsJoinedByString:@""];
}
```

Comment: `stringByTrimmingCharactersInSet` removes only *leading* and *trailing* characters, so `"\nA\nB\n"` would become `"A\nB"`. The middle control character is not replaced.

Comment: Thanks Martin. Yes my first ever contribution and it was wrong:(

Comment: Welcome to SO! Your new code looks correct, you could even remove the call to `stringByTrimmingCharactersInSet`. - (I must admit that I am not a big fan of using `componentsSeparatedByCharactersInSet` to filter a string, because it creates a lot of temporary objects.)

Comment: Actually the `filteredArrayUsingPredicate` call is also not necessary.